# Effect of irrelevant features on Gaussian Process

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm building a machine learning model for prediction of chemical properties for different metallic ensemble. In my model, I'm using Gaussian process to train the model. Now, I'm not sure about the relevance of all my features for the prediction of target value. Is there any mechanism that I can apply within scikit learn framework that will weed out irrelevant features (like LASSO).